# Error sending mail

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I've got the following...

```
  Properties prop = new Properties();
  prop.put(host, "localhost");
  prop.put(host, "25");
```

When I run the following it throws me back the following error...

`javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25;
  nested exception is:`

`java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused`

I don't really understand why it's throwing me this back... anyone have any ideas? my smtp server is in fact up and working as far as I can tell :S

edit: If I understand correctly it's telneting to my machine.. why? it shouldn't be... It's meant to be telneting to `host`.

Comment: Is `telnet localhost 25` responding?

Comment: That's the thing.. why is it going to localhost? It's meant to connect to `host` :S

Comment: `prop.put(host, "localhost");` - looks like it's going to localhost?

Comment: if I change "localhost" in that to anything it still throws the same error with localhost in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have the property to set the host incorrect:

```
prop.put(host, "localhost");
```

This will create a property with the key of whatever is in host and call it localhost. I'm guessing that your property isn't what you think it is so JavaMail is then using the default of localhost.

You propably want this instead:

```
 props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
 props.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
```

Comment: +1: Additionally, `host` is a parameter of the method `sendmail`, which doesn't make sense from my point of view. Because of the wrong properties, `localhost` and `25` is used as default values.